# Use AJAX also when the page get loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm going to build an ajax based app using `jQuery` for JS and `Codeigniter` as the PHP framework.

When the user interact with the app it obviously use ajax to update the page but is that useful when first loading the app or it simply cause the page to slow down?

EDIT: I'll try to be more specific.

Well, I have a static part of the site where the app is showcased and the user can login/sign up then there's the real app.

Each user has some "items" and he can edit them, delete or add new items, items are arranged in several categories and the user can manage these categories.

So I would have 2 simple CRUD: one for items and one for categories.

it would be a lot easier to use only ajax but I've noticed that a lot of dom slow down pages since i'll have to use also a lot of jquery for drag'n drop, effects...

EDIT 2: thanks for the answers but I asked somethng different, if using too much ajax (also for the page load) would slow down the page

Comment: Why not just load the elements needed for the initial page? Surely there's no need to use AJAX as soon as the page loads?

Comment: This is a very broad question and the answer will depend very much on the case at hand, please try to narrow the question down, preferably by specifying the application more thoroughly.

Comment: yes i thought to do so but that might be a problem since i need to use json for ajax requests and while using partial views for the initial one...

Comment: @zrvan i've explained something more in the question

Comment: is it a rails application??? if so please be more specific and add partial details for a better solution

Comment: as specified above it is PHP application built over CodeIgniter, which details fdo you need?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `ajax` function in `document.ready function`.
This will run the ajax call whatever you want on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // put all your jQuery ajax in here.
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(){
        alert('success');
      }
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just the same as any other jQuery AJAX call, but you don't need to assign it to an event.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax('exampleurl', {
    success: function(data) { $('#example').html(data); }
  }

});
```

This runs the $.ajax() call on page load, and replaces the content of the #example div with whatever is loaded on the ajax call.